# Umbraco migration from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, migration, umbraco, umbraco6

I need to migrate from my home SQL Server 2012 Express server to SQL Server 2008 instance at my hoster.

I tried to save backup my server and restore db on hosters server, but server threw exception about SQL Server version compatibility.

Then I have gone to another way and installed on my server SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50). In Management Studio, I have connected to both servers and I have made export data from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008 R2. Exporting was successful and I was happy.

Then I have edited my web.config and IIS settings for my site. I have opened my website and logined to umbraco. All was well, but after I have edited my doctype and clicked save. Umbraco has shown me the YSOD page. With text similar to this:

> Can`t insert value NULL in column "id" the table "MyTable.dbo.umbracoLog"; in column denied values NULL. Error in INSERT.

I can`t understand how to fix this problem.

P.S.: I can`t attach photo because my karma is too low, but I can write links. This is the screenshot of YSOD. It is write  on Russian =)

http://s017.radikal.ru/i404/1402/1c/69baa15293e3.png

Regards, Anton (Siberia)

Comment: That error sounds like umbracoLog should have an identity set on id but doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate scripts and data inserts for your target database version (2008). See the following post for details:

[How do I generate insert statements with Sql server 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273317/how-do-i-generate-insert-statements-with-sql-server-2012)

Comment: In my case it work with some errors. But website is work normal. I found that errors was threw when script started change some constraint of the database. Then I have deleted this alter rows from script and it work perfectly. Thanks